# What are the keyboard shortcut for Knife Tool and Reroute Node for the Node Wrangler for Blender 2.8?

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, workflow

For the Knife Tool, it used to be holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and dragging across a node connection to cancel the node connections, while to create a reroute node, it was holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and dragging across a node connection.

What are the new keyboard shortcut for Knife Tool and Reroute Node for the Node Wrangler for Blender 2.8?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Blender 2.8 it's still in it's beta version, so it's not unusual that some features may not work as expected. Since a few days ago the two shortcut (which are not related to the node wrangler addon) were the same (ctrl to cut, shift to add). I think they may come back soon.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell nothing has changed, the node wrangler works just fine.

Make sure the addon is enabled in the system preferences, it is not enabled by default. If you use it constantly make sure you save the preferences to make enable the addon permanently.

Then cut while pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>.

[image]

To reroute use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and move the mouse across the connection.

[image]

To do lazy connect use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>
+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I cannot get this to work, I am on 2.80.74 and have Node Wrangler 3.35.

Comment: This DOES work, only you need to be in Select Mode, NOT Lasso, Box or Circle Select. Just wanted to mention this, since Box Select is the default.

Answer (score 1):

[image: ToolBar Shader Editor]

As of yet, there are no shortcuts for this anymore. The current workflow is to open the Tool-Panel with <kbd>T</kbd> and then selecting the *Cut Links Tool* (the one with the scissors), holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while dragging it over a noodle will add a *Reroute*.

I have mapped the Shortcut manually, and now it works again. Even in Box and Lasso Select Modes. The drawback of this is, that deselecting, which had the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Key before is blocked by this.

[image: Node CUt Shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

In Version 2.82a docs show it is the 'slash' / character now.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/node/node_wrangler.html#add-reroutes-to-outputs

okay so whatever is selected then choose add to all outputs, there is of course similar shown after pressing 'n' in the "Node Wrangler" vertical tab (yes the addon needs to be active).